# Is there a tenant ID or equivalent for Google business (G Suite) accounts to differentiate between tenants?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-signin, google-openid, google-identity

Our application uses Microsoft and Google logins via OpenID Connect to authenticate users. We want to identity business/organizational users and their tenants using the claims/tokens emitted by the identity platform or API.

In Microsoft Identity Platform/Azure AD, there is a `tid` claim that can easily identity the tenant of an account. An Azure AD tenant can have many custom domains, but they will all have the same tenant ID.

What is the equivalent of this for Google business/education accounts (G Suite)? The closest thing I found so far is an `hd` claim that gets emitted for G Suite accounts which contains the domain name (it's available from the email address itself anyway), **but the problem is that a tenant can have multiple domain names, so using the domain name alone won't be accurate.**

If it is not available from the OIDC claims/tokens during the sign-in workflow, can we obtain this from an API at least?

Answer (score 0):

`hd` will be present only for G Suite / Workspace accounts, it's absence identifies a consumer account.

You may be looking for Resource Manager [organizations.list](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/organizations/list) and friends.

It may be helpful to think of this question more along the lines of who is the currently signed-in user. User's must first choose a single account to sign into, consent to share their profile, and only then the ID token is shared. `hd` is scoped and reflects the currently signed-in account, you could reasonably expect an individual to have multiple accounts: both consumer and workspace. Mentioning this as once you think about multiple organizations and consumer accounts the hierarchy and order of sign-in operations matters. Obtaining a list of domain names, organizations and tenants isn't something an ID token is designed for.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the resource manager API! Yes it doesn't have to be from the `id_token`. I don't mind doing another API call so long as I can find the G Suite tenant ID of a G Suite user, no matter how many domains exist under that tenant. So looking at the doc, there is `directoryCustomerId` that represents "The G Suite / Workspace customer id used in the Directory API". Could this be the equivalent of the tenant ID (like Azure AD tenant ID) I was looking for?

Comment: Try [Limitations with multiple domains](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/182081) and the Directory API [Manage Users and Aliases](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users).

Comment: @bid I want to clarify my use scenario. My app has no interest in retrieving/managing G Suite users/tenants on Google's side. It just uses the standard Oauth2/OIDC sign-in via Google Identity. What we do want to do, is to be able to recognize G Suite users from the same org/tenant on our side. For this purpose, if we request the necessary scope (`cloud-platform.read-only`), and obtain the `directoryCustomerId`, can we then say: all of our users who signed in via Google with the same `directoryCustomerId` must belong to the same G Suite tenant, with confidence? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, `hd` let's you identify G Suite users, from there you could use the value of `hd` to match a domain in your list of tenants. Of course, you'd need to have an authoritative list of all possible tenants.

Comment: The problem is that `hd` contains just one domain, but a G Suite tenant can have multiple domains. For example, ACME Corp has a G Suite tenant with `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`. Because my app does not have access to a list of all domains associated with a G Suite tenant, it would treat `jack@domain1.com` and `jill@domain2.com` as two users from two tenants, even though they should be in the same tenant. This is why I want to obtain a tenant ID. So Jack and Jill can have different domain names, but the same tenant ID, allowing my app to recognize them accurately.

Comment: Understood. It may be helpful to think in terms of permissions and scope; organizations and domains are not equivalent. Sign-in communicates only the domain to which the user has signed in. IAM roles govern which users can call the APIs to view/edit organizational relationships.